# Bubble pop using boolean in java.

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, boolean, bubble-sort

```
import java.util.*;

public class Zhangbubble
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int Bub[] = new int[6];
        Random randy = new Random();
        boolean Done = false;
        for (int x=0; x<6; x++)
        {
            Bub[x] = randy.nextInt(100);
            System.out.println (Bub[x]);
        }
            System.out.println ("This is the original array");
            while (! Done)
            {
                Done = true;
                for (int x = 0; x<Bub.length-1; x++)
                {
                if(Bub[x+1] > Bub[x])
                {
                    int temp = Bub[x];
                    Bub[x] = Bub[x+1];
                    temp = Bub[x+1];
                    Done = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    Done = false;
                }

            }
            for(int x = 0; x<6; x++)
            {
                System.out.print(Bub[x]+" ");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

So my programming teacher asked us to make a bubble sort in java using a boolean.  His example shows the code in a while loop with for loops.  This code is suppose to continuously sort until it has the numbers in the array organized from least to greatest.  However, I'm really lost and I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: As a hint, you might want to follow Java conventions in your code -- variable names' first letter is lower-cased, and only the first letters of subsequent words are upper-cased e.g. testGears -- see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html#naming .  Might want to pluralize your bub and give it a more descriptive name too.

That'd not only help with readability for those trying to help, but for yourself as well a few months down the road - less things to figure out.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code using a debugger and/or inserting frequent print statements with variable values?  I think you'll learn more that way then trying to get the answer from Stack Overflow.

Comment: have you tried using a debugger?  set some breakpoints in your code, and step through, and see what it actually does.  To me, without looking long, it looks like done is set to false in both the if and the else, so it is never done?

Comment: @jeff_kile great minds think alike! :D

Comment: I tried debugging it and I found out that instead of swapping the two numbers, it just started spitting out one number so if I start with a random chain of six numbers, it would end up as a chain of more than six numbers that either have the same value or different values that present multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your switching algorithm. You are assigning temp twice.

```
 int temp = Bub[x];
            Bub[x] = Bub[x+1];
            temp = Bub[x+1]; //Here should assign Bub[x+1] to temp
            //Example: Bub[x+1] = temp
```

edit-Actually, there could be some improvement in the sorting algorithm itself, too. Personally, I like to do it this way:

```
public class Sort {
    private static int[] array = { 3, 8, -1, 7, 0, 3 };

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            for(int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {

                if(array[i] > array[j]) {
                    int temp = array[i];
                    array[i] = array[j];
                    array[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried that but all it did was java told me it caused a "lack of precison"

Answer (score 0):

this working

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {


   int Bub[] = new int[6];
    Random randy = new Random();
    boolean Done = false;
    for (int x=0; x<6; x++)
    {
        Bub[x] = randy.nextInt(100);
        System.out.println (Bub[x]);
    }
        System.out.println ("This is the original array");
        while ( ! Done)
        {

            for (int x = 0; x<Bub.length-1; x++)
            {
            if(Bub[x+1] > Bub[x])
            {
                int temp = Bub[x];
                Bub[x] = Bub[x+1];
                Bub[x+1]=temp ;
                Done = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Done = false;
            }

        }
        for(int x = 0; x<6; x++)
        {
            System.out.print(Bub[x]+" ");
        }
         Done = true;
    }


}
```

Comment: yeah it is.  I had that code, pretty much exactly at first but it just isn't working.  The code looks right but it just doesn't work.